# How to increase the width of bootstrap card and move to top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have designed the bootstrap card with my form elements because of more form elements bootstrap card falling down and i am not able to see some form 
How to increase width of card or how should i move to bit more top to get all my form elements i have placed col-lg-20 on top of card but its not working

Fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/

```
<div class="col-lg-20">
            <div class="login-box card">            
            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" action="index.html">
                    <h3 class="box-title m-b-20">Set up your company</h3>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Company Name"> </div>
                    </div>


                                 <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Select Company Type--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>

                   <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Company Official website"> </div>
                    </div>


                                 <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Select Phone Type--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->                                   
                                        </div>


                                                <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Ext</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                        </div>


                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Employees</label>
                                                    <div class="form-check">
                                                        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" checked class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description"> 0 - 50</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description">50 - 100</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                         <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description">100 - 250</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                         <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description">250 - 500</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                         <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description">500 - 1000</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                         <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                                                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                            <span class="custom-control-description">above 1000</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">                      
                                <input type="file" id="input-file-now" class="dropify" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

                <p>Please enter your company mailing address and different branches your are located at :</p>

                 <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Address type--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Select Country--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Select State--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Category</label> -->
                                                    <select class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                                                        <option value="Category 1">--Select City--</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 3">Category 5</option>
                                                        <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Zip"> </div>
                    </div>



                </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.login-register{
    overflow: scroll; 
    padding: 5% 0; 
}

.login-box{
  width:800px; adjust this value according your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First a fall there's no such thing as col-lg-20.
Bootstrap has a grid system of max 12 columns.

You just need to add this rules to your CSS:

```
.login-register{
    overflow: scroll; /* Alowing the card to scroll */
    padding: 5% 0; /*For shifting your card at the top of the page */
}
```

Comment: Overflow is working but how to increase width of card

Comment: In your CSS login-card has a fixed width of 400px. change the width accroding to your requirement.